# RPC float result error

Tags: c, rpc

I am writing a simple RPC program that adds, subtracts, multiplies and divides two `int` numbers. I wrote the `int` then I used `int` to generate files. When I execute the server, and the client gives it two simple integers, the server gives big float numbers.

What is wrong?

The `file.x` is as follows:

```
struct entier{
int a;
int b;};
typedef struct entier params;
struct resultat{
float result;
int   resp;};
typedef struct resultat res;
program CALC{
version VERS1{
    void CALCUL_NULL(void)=0;
    res ADDITION(params )=1;
    res SOUTRACTION(params)=2;
    res MULTIPLICATION(params)=3;
    res DIVISION(params)=4;
         }=1;
}=0x20000001;
```

The server code is:

```
/*
 * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "file.h"

void *
calcul_null_1_svc(void *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static char * result;

    /*
     * insert server code here
     */

    return (void *) &result;
}

res *
addition_1_svc(params *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static res  result;

    result.result= argp->a + argp->b;
    result.resp=0;

    return &result;
}

res *
soutraction_1_svc(params *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static res  result;

    result.result= argp->a - argp->b;
    result.resp=0;

    return &result;
}

res *
multiplication_1_svc(params *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static res  result;

    result.result= argp->a * argp->b;
    result.resp=0;

    return &result;
}

res *
division_1_svc(params *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static res  result;

    if(argp->b ==0)
    result.resp=1;
    else
        result.result= argp->a / argp->b;

    return &result;
}
```

The client:

```
/*
* This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "file.h"

int x;
int y;
void
calc_1(char *host)
{
    CLIENT *clnt;
    void  *result_1;
    char *calcul_null_1_arg;

    params  arguments;
    arguments.a=(float)x;
    arguments.b=(float)y;
    res  *respons;


#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt = clnt_create (host, CALC, VERS1, "udp");
    if (clnt == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror (host);
        exit (1);
    }
    #endif  /* DEBUG */

    result_1 = calcul_null_1((void*)&calcul_null_1_arg, clnt);
    if (result_1 == (void *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
    respons = addition_1(&arguments, clnt);
    printf("the additon is%f \n",respons->result);
    if (respons == (res *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
    respons = soutraction_1(&arguments, clnt);
    printf("the substraction is %f \n",respons->result);
    if (respons == (res *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
    respons = multiplication_1(&arguments, clnt);
        printf("the multiplication is %f \n",respons->result);
    if (respons == (res *) NULL) {
    clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }
    respons = division_1(&arguments, clnt);
    if (respons == (res *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    if(respons->resp==1)
    printf("error division by zero");
    else printf("the division is %f \n",respons->result);
    }
#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host;

    if (argc < 4) {
        printf ("usage: %s server_host\n", argv[0]);
        exit (1);
    }
    host = argv[1];
    x=(int) argv[2];
    y= (int) argv[3];
    calc_1 (host);
exit (0);
}
```

The execution:

```
blitzkrieg@blitzkrieg-TravelMate-P253:~/Desktop/rpc$ ./client localhost 5 6
the additon is2131577472.000000
the substraction is -2.000000
the multiplication is -88320960.000000
blitzkrieg@blitzkrieg-TravelMate-P253:~/Desktop/rpc$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have `entier.a` and `entier.b` defined as integers, but are passing them in as floats.  I would expect this to generate an error at compile time, but if not, then it could be trying to integer operate on floating point numbers, which won't work very well.

```
struct entier{
  int a;
  int b;
};

typedef struct entier params;
```

and

```
params  arguments;
arguments.a=(float)x;
arguments.b=(float)y;
```

---

**Problem 2**

```
x=(int) argv[2];
y= (int) argv[3];
```

In C, this will be taking a `char *` and trying to process it as an `int`, which won't do what you want either.  You need to to use sort of converting function to get these as integers.  `atoi()` may do what you need here.

Are you sure you are not receiving warnings about this when compiling as this code should not be functioning as is, due to massive conversion issues from `int` to `float` and `char[]` to `int`.

Comment: yes yes this is an update but before i've pass them integers but still show the same

Comment: I would expect some warnings though at least.  Anyways, convert your input strings to integers, don't cast them as floats, and try again.  I would also print out the input via a `printf("%d %d\n", arguments.a, arguments.a)` to be sure they are the numbers you are expecting.

Comment: Excellent.  Then please upvote my answer and cilck the check mark underneath it so that I receive credit.